# How to execute tasks sequentially? Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, completionhandler

Inside `@IBaction func login` in else statement I call `startObserving()`. Why is it not executed on the main thread?
This statement    `print("executed")` is executed before the code inside `self.startObservingDB(callback: { (snapValue) in` is evaluated in the else statement.
I don't want startObservingDB to return before it receives snapValue from Firebase. How can I make startObservingDB in the else statement wait for Firebase to complete its tasks and then continue execution?

```
@IBAction func logIn(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (authData, error) in

   if error != nil {
            //
        } else {
       self.startObservingDB(callback: { (snapValue) in
        if snapValue != nil {
           print("should segue")
               self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LogInToTabBarController", sender: self)
                    }
                })//end of startObservingDB


//prints before code in else statement, inside self.startObservingDB(callback: { (snapValue)   is evaluated
print("executed")
        }
    })
}



 func startObservingDB(callback:@escaping ((_ snapShot:FIRDataSnapshot?) -> Void)){
    // check if user is singed in
     guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid  else {
         return
     }

   dbRef.child(uid).child("profile").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        //pass snapshot vale to callback closure so as to make the values available when calling startObservingDB
        callback(snapshot.value as? FIRDataSnapshot)


    }, withCancel: { (Error:Any) in
        print("Error firebase \(Error)")
        print("You are not a cleaner")

    })
    dbRef.removeAllObservers()
}  // end of startObserving
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to startObservingDB *IS* happening on the same thread.

However, you'll notice that the call to observeSingleEvent takes a callback. This is because internally that call kicks off a new background thread.  That method, once it completes, will comeback and then call your callback.

So the sequence of events you're seeing is:

- Thread A: startObservingDB starts
- Thread A: observeSingleEvent starts
- Thread B: starts doing internal work for observeSingleEvent
- Thread A: observeSingleEvent returns
- Thread A: startObservingDB returns
- Thread A: print("executed")
- Thread B: Finishes doing internal work for observeSingleEvent
- Thread B: Executes the callback from the "with" on observeSingleEvent
- Thread B: Executes callback(snapshot.value as? FIRDataSnapshot)
- Thread B: print("should segue")
- Thread B: performSegue

Comment: How can I make my method startObservingDB to wait until  `Thread B: Executes callback(snapshot.value as? FIRDataSnapshot)` finishes? I need to check `if snapValue != nil` inside `self.startObservingDB(callback: { (snapValue) in` and I assume that in order for this to happen, I have to make `startObservingDB` wait until firebase finishes the work. Thank you

Comment: I think you just have a misunderstanding about how blocks work, you're already getting the behavior you just mentioned. When `callback(snapshot.value as? FIRDataSnapshot)` executes, it is running the block that you passed in with this call `self.startObservingDB(callback: { (snapValue) in`.  They're the same piece of code, like calling a method runs the code in that method.